# Jquery content loading with php sessions

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am trying to load the content in my jquery script using php sessions, I am new to jquery and following if statement doesn't seem to be working although i can see the variable getting assigned

```
<script>
var cc = <?php echo $_SESSION['abc'];?>
$(document).ready(function() {
if(cc == "abc"){
  $('.content').load("main.php");}
  else{
  $('.content').load("login.php");}
  }
});</script>
```

also I need to check the sessions while loading other content in my page like:

```
<script>
$("a:contains('Tracker')").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();//to stop refresh/redirecting
$(".content").load("tracker.php");
});

$("a:contains('Orderbook')").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();//to stop refresh/redirecting
$(".content").load("orderbook.php");
});

$("a:contains('Home')").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();//to stop refresh/redirecting
$(".content").load("main.php");
});

</script>
```

Comment: Make sure the data type of `cc` is `string`, check your console for errors, it may tell you `Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined`

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for this.. You can use PHP also for checking session an include pages.

Comment: I am starting the session at the beginning of the so abc has already been assigned! @AniketSahrawat

Comment: @GYaN I am trying to learn jquery so that's the reason !

Comment: Okay............

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list this at the if statement

Comment: `var cc = <?php echo $_SESSION['abc'];?>;`, semicolon is missing at the end

Comment: Did that still no effect @AniketSahrawat

Comment: Same error as above @AniketSahrawat

Comment: fixed it seems I was adding extra } after the if else statement! Thank you so much!@AniketSahrawat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made one mistake with the assign the php session to JavaScript variable other are good.

Your Code:

```
var cc = <?php echo $_SESSION['abc'];?>
```

Replace with:

```
var cc = '<?php echo $_SESSION['abc'];?>';
```

You just mess the quote before the session.

Comment: @HarisShah Try `var cc = "<?php echo isset($_SESSION['abc']) ? $_SESSION['abc'] : '';?>";`, also please verify your session is started and value is assign to `abc` variable.